# How to identify clusters of heterogeneous balls in a bin in 2D

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I'm looking for the optimal algorithm in Swift 3x or 4 to determine if there are any clusters of like-colored balls in a bin. I need to make this calculation many times per second on iOS so would it be appropriate to use the accelerate framework? I'm not sure how to approach this problem.

given a bin full of balls, in dynamic motion, I would like, for example, to be able to apply number labels to the balls as in this diagram.

the numbers would animate, updating in each frame, to identify the size of their cluster.

there would be a reasonable finite distance, such as `r * 1.1` for including a neighboring ball in a given cluster.

the clusters of balls could go into an array of clusters, perhaps...

[image: numbered clusters of balls in a bin]

I liked the idea in the comments below with bucket container nodes, but the comment is reminiscent of Fermat. Could anybody elaborate on that in swift code?

Comment: This is sprite kit right?  You can place in invisible children node buckets to help with your organization based on color, and just count the children in the invisible buckets when need be

Comment: That sounds interesting. Could you elaborate?

Comment: The clusters would only be counted if all the members of each cluster are linked by a short distance (with a definable tolerance)

Comment: Yeah, when 2 of the same color nodes touch each other, you can place them into an SKNode and treat it like a container,  then when the 3rd one touches, you can see if the node it touches is in  a container, and continue to add to this new container.  It is a bit of work, that is why I haven't wrote an answer lol

Comment: Hm but would it be fast enough to update cleanly each frame? So these child nodes would be a little larger than the balls, say, equal to the tolerance radius? There may be on the order of a few hundred balls on the screen at any given time...

Comment: How do you deal with them moving out of range? How do ones already in a bucket get removed? Do you think it's necessary to repeat the entire process each pass?

Comment: the child node has no size, it is just grouping your balls together.  The work is done at linking so it would be fast.  Also since you have them in a special container,  you can quickly remove the container, thus removing all the balls

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148148/discussion-between-dave-kliman-and-knight0fdragon).

Comment: You can represent you data as a graph with ball-nodes and links (two nodes are linked = same ball color and balls touch each other). Then the problem becomes this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)

Comment: Yes, in clusters, as stated above.

Comment: using `didBegin / didEnd` is not going to generate the output you provided in the picture. Some balls are not touching, yet counted as in the same group. SK physics would require them to be touching.

Comment: Yes I am aware, which is why for that model as I describe above, there needs to be a 10% radius tolerance, probably accomplished by having an extra, invisible sphere around each item, which has a larger radius and a physics body, but is pinned.

Comment: I've been working on something and the easiest solution I have is to have a second physicsbody.. I'm severely concerned about performance, because you are now doubling everything with that, in addition to the extra checks outside of the physics loop

Comment: which devices are you targeting?

Comment: Any iOS. I'd do a second physics body but I thought each sprite could only have one.

Comment: THAT'S WHAT I'M SAYING ;D  Would have to have extra code to "sync" the two, in addition to double (or more) the work on the physics engine. Also, you need to @Fluidity me so I get notified please

Comment: Also, "any iOS" isn't an answer, because you are using sprite kit and swift 3, so Xcode is only going to allow you to do iOS 8 minimally... which means you have to get this running on SLOW hardware, which I simply don't see happening.. but it may be possible.

Comment: @Fluidity fact is there are many games that employ a similar algorithm, without trouble, such as toy blast, which runs just fine on an iPhone 5.

Comment: well, my two ideas are now #1, an enumerated check each frame, with something like a `if didMovePosition { update() }` or, doing something with `didBegin / didEnd` with two physicsBodies

Comment: will try to have something 4 u before grace period is ended.

Comment: STIll workong on your solution

Comment: it needs to be completely generic to account for any types of game pieces with many different possible behaviors in 2 or 3d.... the more generic the better.. even just a protocol isn't a bad idea... utilizing spite kit isn't so bad with an extension of physicscontact and delegate, perhaps.

Comment: Please remember to use @Fluidity so I get notified. My current approach is generic only in regards to spheres. If you need something completely generic, then that would require a ton of work on the physics engine. The approach I'm using would work in 3d as well, and you could modify it to work with other shapes.